# Run content plugin in Category blog layout

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm running Joomla 2.5 and I need to call a content plugin in a category blog layout. I have tried overriding the default `blog` layout with the following code so that the plugin would run:

```
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content', 'name_of_plugin');
$dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array (& $item, & $item->params, 0));
```

However, the plugin is not loading and it gives me the following warning:

```
 Warning: Parameter 3 to name_of_plugin::onContentPrepare() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 71
```

Any help as to how I can integrate the plugin into the category blog layout would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, 
    array (& $item, & $item->params, 0)
is not a reference.

Solution:

```
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content', 'name_of_plugin');
$call = array (& $item, & $item->params, 0);
$dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', $call);
```